# How to mark multiple CButtons as clicked in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a set of normal CButtons in MFC when a user clickes on one button its appearence should be changed to reflex the idea that it has been clicked sth like in the picture

[image]

i tried to change the style of the clicked button using the following code

```
button->SetButtonStyle(BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON);
Invalidate();
```

but the problem with this approach is that just one button at time is allowed to be marked so any ideas ?  is the only way is to use a bitmap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CButton::SetState

This page has an example of what you want to do:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebw1hfe8(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebw1hfe8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks i am using this function in a message handler ON_CONTROL_RANGE 
and i noticed that the call of SetState is forcing the message handler to be called again (twice) !